# Disk space 100% used after failed SSH

Tags: partitioning, mount, ssh

I'm using a Google Cloud VM running Linux and mounted an external storage to `/data1` and began SSH'ing files into my server. However, I incorrectly uploaded these to a different directory and got "Out of space" error during the operation. The file does not seem to have been uploaded, yet Linux insists I am out of disk space on my primary partition (`/dev/sda1`):

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs           395M  5.3M  390M   2% /run
/dev/sda1       9.7G  9.2G  6.9M 100% /
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda15      124M  7.9M  116M   7% /boot/efi
/dev/sdb        492G   73M  492G   1% /data1
tmpfs           395M     0  395M   0% /run/user/1001
```

There seems to be 9.2G used in `/dev/sda1`, however I can't seem to find the culprit. Running `du` seems to show contradictory results.

```
# du -sh /
2.2G    /
```

So it seems like there is only 2.2GB used on the root directory, yet `df -h` insists that 9.2G has been used. I'm almost certain this is from the failed SSH (I was SSH'ing a file larger than the disk space available), however, I can't seem to remove it. I've tried rebooting my server to no avail, can any Linux experts enlighten me on how I could further debug this?

Comment: Probably you wrote to `/data1` while `/dev/sdb` wasn't mounted there - now that it is mounted, `du` can't see the files

Comment: @steeldriver, thanks for the quick reply! If that is the case, could I unmount the disk, clear /data1, and then remount to see if the problem goes away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From comments @steeldriver, the problem was that I had uploaded the files to `/data1` while `/dev/sdb` was not mounted there, this was fixed by unmounting the disk, then `sudo rm -rf /data1` and then remounting.

```
$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev
tmpfs           395M  5.3M  390M   2% /run
/dev/sda1       9.7G  2.2G  7.1G  24% /
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda15      124M  7.9M  116M   7% /boot/efi
tmpfs           395M     0  395M   0% /run/user/1001
/dev/sdb        492G   73M  492G   1% /data1
```